# Amazon S3 getObject Bucket Policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a policy declared like this on my bucket:

```
{
    "Sid": "Policy 1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "aws:Referer": "http://example.com/*"
        }
    }
}
```

I declared a condition aws:Referer because I want the objects to be accessed from a certain domain only. From my node API, i add the s3 object as attachment for internal download.

```
this.response.attachment(Key)
this.body = request(Location, { encoding: null })
```

However, it will always produce an **"Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 403"**. The file can be uploaded to S3 bucket and I can get the object already. The problem is with this part for download. I tried removing the condition in the policy and the download works fine. What may be the problem  for my bucket policy?

Comment: Not an answer, but why are you allowing anyone to Delete and Upload objects to your bucket in this policy? It's not normally the sort of thing you'd allow. (It will probably fail due to referer, but worth asking.)

Comment: hi @JohnRotenstein this was just a sample. the principal was actually the arn w/ iam user for my resource.